# Trying to figure out the two-part authentication process. Can anyone give direct instructions?

Tags: security, btce, authentication, two-factor

I'm using btc-e.com verification, in the Finances section.
It supplies two key codes and has a square bar code to scan.
I've set up my google account for two-part verification, and google is ALSO supplying a keycode.
I've downloaded the bar code reader, but apparently I have to do something with these 3 keycodes before the bar code reader will give it's 6 digit code for me to enter in the btc-e.com security/finances section.

Can anyone tell me where I enter the google security code?  And also tell me where I'm supposed to enter the two btc-e.com security codes?
I need explicit step by step instructions, which I can't seem to find online.
thanks,
PS. I am a complete noob at this.  I've read similar questions and answers on this forum already, but they don't explain WHERE these codes are really supposed to go.

Comment: Are you using [Google Auth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2) for Android or [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/google-authenticator/id388497605)